# Rails: "t.references" not working when creating index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

```
class CreateBallots < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ballots do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :score
      t.references :election
      t.string :key
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :ballots, :user
    add_index :ballots, :score
    add_index :ballots, :election
  end
end
```

results in:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table ballots has no column named user: CREATE  INDEX "index_ballots_on_user" ON "ballots" ("user")/home/muhd/awesomevote/db/migrate/20130624024349_create_ballots.rb:10:in `change'
```

I thought `t.references` was supposed to handle that for me?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You forgot to add "_id" like this:

```
add_index :ballots, :user_id
```

or, if you want it indexed automatically:

```
t.references :user, index: true
```

More info: [add_index](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) , [references](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references)

HTH

Comment: Ah, okay.  I would have thought that the same syntax would be used between t.references and add_index, but I guess that's not the case here.  Thanks for the tip for doing `index: true`; I didn't know about that.

Comment: Yes, it is not really obvious but "t.references" references the "user" by adding "user_id" column :)

Comment: In Rails 5 `t.references :user` would create index by default

Answer (score 17):

The answer above is correct, but be aware that:

`t.references :user, index: true` is only available in [Rails 4.0 & up.](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5262/files)

In earlier versions of Rails (3.x), `index: true` will fail silently, leaving you without an index on that table.  For Rails 3.2.x & down, use [the older syntax](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Migration):

`add_index :ballots, :user_id`

Or in full using your example:

```
class CreateBallots < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ballots do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :score
      t.references :election
      t.string :key
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :ballots, :user_id
    add_index :ballots, :score_id
    add_index :ballots, :election_id
  end
end
```