# Rails how to create relationships between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, shopify, shopify-app

I'm developing a Shopify App and I'm trying to create a relationship in my database where I have a Shop model and an Address model, and one shop can have different addresses and every address is related to one shop.

So I have this:

**models/shop.rb**

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ShopifyApp::SessionStorage
  has_many :addresses
end
```

**models/address.rb**

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :shop
end
```

**db/migrate/create_shops.rb**

```
class CreateShops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    has_many :addresses
  def self.up
    create_table :shops  do |t|
      t.string :shopify_domain, null: false
      t.string :shopify_token, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :shops, :shopify_domain, unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :shops
  end
end
```

**db/migrate/create_shops.rb**

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.text :Address1
      t.text :Address2
      t.string :Postal
      t.string :Phone
      t.string :City

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I think I don't have this well...
**So, how can I add addresses to a shop in my database?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here:

```
class CreateShops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  has_many :addresses
  def self.up
    create_table :shops  do |t|
      t.string :shopify_domain, null: false
      t.string :shopify_token, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :shops, :shopify_domain, unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :shops
  end
end
```

you do not want `has_many :addresses`. And this:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.text :Address1
      t.text :Address2
      t.string :Postal
      t.string :Phone
      t.string :City

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

should be like this:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table    :addresses do |t|
      t.references  :shop
      t.string      :address_1
      t.string      :address_2
      t.string      :postal
      t.string      :phone
      t.string      :city

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

As mentioned by @engineersmnky in the comments, as of Rails 5, an index is automatically created on the foreign key.

For future readers who may not be on Rails 5 (or later, depending on how far into the future you are) who want to add an index to the foreign key...

If you're on Rails 4.x, then do:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table    :addresses do |t|
      t.references  :shop, index: true
      t.string      :address_1
      t.string      :address_2
      t.string      :postal
      t.string      :phone
      t.string      :city

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If you're earlier than Rails 4.x, then see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478669/rails-t-references-not-working-when-creating-index).

Comment: `string` is probably sufficient for an address line as well unless you know someone with a 4000+ character address

Comment: Ha! Good catch. I wasn't even paying attention to the field type for the other fields (my bad). Thanks!

Comment: Also `references` adds the index by default so the second example is redundant

Comment: @engineersmnky - Out of curiosity, is that new to Rails 5? I was looking at the [apidock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table/references) for Rails 4.2.7 and it didn't *seem* to indicate that the index was added by default. Naturally, I may have misunderstood. I'm not on Rails 5 yet, so I'm missing on some of the new stuff.

Comment: Indeed it is [Docs for 4.2.7](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference) and [Docs for 5.X](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)

Comment: Thanks! (I should have looked it up myself. Sorry.) Guess I'll have to get modern one of these days.

Comment: We still have 1.9.3 rails 3 applications rolling around :)